# Javascript document.referrer is looping

Tags: javascript, redirect, indexof, intranet, referrer

I'm a new programmer so I'm open to learning more standard ways of programming.

Currently:
I'm having an issue with redirecting users who come from certain sites.

**This is an intranet website I'm working on.**

```js
 //Redirect to the correct FAQ page
var url = document.referrer;
 //If both are not in the http referrer do nothing
if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('srs') === -1 && url.toLowerCase().indexOf('pts2') === -1) {
  //PTS2 and SRS are not present in http referrer
}
 //If pts2 is not detected SRS must of been redirect to srs_faq
 else if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('pts2') === -1) {
  //SRS was detected, redirect to SRS's FAQ
  window.location.replace("http://abc/qa_faqs/srs_faq.html");
}
 //Do nothing for PTS2 referrer
 else if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf('srs') === -1) {
  //PTS2 is present in http referrer 
} else {
  //If this code runs, the gods are cruel.
  alert(url);
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

---

I'm new and didn't explain my solution in my own post. So here is the hack I came up with to solve the referrer issue I had.

I edited the code to each individual page to fit the redirection I wanted.

```js
//Gives me the referrer
var urlR = document.referrer;

//If it did not come from any known referrer, Do Nothing
if (urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("pts2") === -1 && urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("srs") === -1 && urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("pts_faq") === -1 && urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("srs_faq") === -1) {
  //SRS and PTS2 are not present in http referrer
}

//Else if srs & srs_faq & pts_faq are not present, Redirect to pts_faq because redirecter must be coming from pts2
else if (urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("srs") === -1 && urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("srs_faq") === -1 && urlR.toLowerCase().indexOf("pts_faq") === -1) {
  window.location.replace("http://pbc/qa_faqs/pts_faq.html");
  //Redirects users to pts_faq
}
```

If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: Well if the code is on the page you are sending them too of course it will keep on looping.

Comment: http://abc/SRS/ going to the http://abc/qa_faqs/srs_faq.html page and http://abc/SRS/ going to the http://abc/qa_faqs/srs_faq.html and getting redirected to the http://abc/qa_faqs/pts_faq.html page | The script will be at the faq pages